# Calculate optimal sample size given a response proportion and desired power for 2:1 trial

Tags: r

Im trying to calculate the sample size using `pwr` package in R. I've already done it to same sample sizes to both groups (1:1), but im struggling to find out how to replicate this for a 2:1 sampling ratio.

This is the code I used:

`pwr.2p.test(h = ES.h(p1 = 0.5, p2 = 0.6), sig.level = 0.05, power = 0.8, alternative = "greater")`

As I said, this worked correctly to calculate optimal sample size for 1:1 sampling ratio. Im trying to find out if there is any kind of argument to specify the ratio, or even another function / package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your calculation as given makes sense; the power is calculated for `p1 - p2` so specifying a one-sided "greater" alternative when `p1 < p2` will result in only type I assertions.

Either way, the `pwr` package does provide a function for unequal sample sizes, but it doesn't allow you to condition on a *ratio* of these sizes -- you have to provide both of them or leave one to be solved freely.

You can easily wrap that function into a solver that does let you specify only the ratio of sample sizes though, for example:

```r
library(pwr)
power_2n <- function(n, target = .80) {
   pwr.2p2n.test(h = ES.h(p1 = 0.5, p2 = 0.6),
                 n1 = 2*n, n2 = n, sig.level = 0.05)$power - target
}

uniroot(power_2n, c(2, 500))
#> $root
#> [1] 290.3758     ## This is your n (and the other group needs 2n)
```

A quick sanity check in SAS PROC POWER returns the same solution (overall N=870). This is for a two-sided alternative as the one-sided was invalid as you had it specified & it wasn't clear which of the two groups you wanted to double, so I used `n1` though that's easily swapped. Do keep in mind that the most powerful comparison is always going to be with balanced sample sizes.